# Tracert behaviour explanation

Tags: ping, traceroute

[image]

Sorry if my question is trivial, I tried to tracert to an ip address, and after first 12 hops I got request timed out for the rest, until reach a maximum of 30 hops.

I assume that the machine is up and running since the list is refreshed (in the list , even though ping gives request time out). I know basic things from firewalls and gateways and how they can turn ping reply's off etc.

Question: what is the following behavior , if the host is not reachable why the TTL are increasing ? is this a packet loop for some reason ? Any chance the real location of the server is somewhere else and is passing through myriad proxies and thus 30+ hops?

Comment: this seems to by a typical behavior , but the answers i got from Hao and David does not explain why to see this typical behavior if you consider most probably there are no 30+ hops

Answer (score 3):

Tracert will keep going until it reaches 30 hop counts. Your screenshot shows that it entered the blocked area where ICMP request packets are ignored.

You might see another situation where some packets in the middle are timedout, and it replies after that. It depends on the device that receives the ICMP request packet from your client. Tracert command increases TTL by one unit to reach further device on the path, if that device blocks or doesn't answer your ICMP Request, you got the timedout message. Next step, your tracert command will try another router behind the previous one. At each steps, it totally depends on the destination router.

Answer (score 2):

The TTL is increasing because the traceroute tool is trying to reach machines further away. There might be three machines in a row that don't permit traceroute replies and then one that does. Unless it checks, traceroute doesn't know.